# How to call a custom cmake script only when files are updated?

Tags: cmake

I want to run an JavaScript minifier only when my JavaScript files are updated.
I know how to do this in make, but not in CMakelist.
Currently I have a script that minifies the JavaScript files, but it runs any time any files update.

```
add_custom_target(MINI-JS ALL DEPENDS ${JS_FILES}
    COMMAND rm -f ../projectv/js/all-min.js
    COMMAND cat ${JS_FILES} | jsmin >> ../projectv/js/all-min.js
)
```

Edit: Tsyvarev's comment seems to suggest this:

```
add_custom_command(OUTPUT ../projectv/js/all-min.js
    DEPENDS ${JS_FILES}
    COMMAND rm -f ../projectv/js/all-min.js
    COMMAND cat ${JS_FILES} | jsmin >> ../projectv/js/all-min.js
)
add_custom_target(MINI-JS ALL DEPENDS ../projectv/js/all-min.js)
```

This never updates, even when the JavaScript files change.  Am I missing something?

Comment: Make you `add_custom_target` to depend on the resulting file - `../projectv/js/all-min.js` and move its COMMAND's to  `add_custom_command` call, which OUTPUT is that file and which DEPENDS on `${JS_FILES}`.

Comment: How do you set the value of `JS_FILES`?

Comment: Holtorf make sure to use absolute paths if you can. Relative paths can cause issues. Not saying that's your problems but it might make debugging easier.

Comment: Relative paths without setting the WORKING_DIRECTORY argument sounds like it might cause issues to me.

Comment: ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/../projectv/js/all-min.js is what I'm suggessting. Or whatever that file output is relative to.

Comment: @jpr33 oh for the output file? Ah, yes indeed.

Comment: Yes for the output file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code below should work. In my example I'm using [CMake command line tool -E mode](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake.1.html?highlight=cmake%20cli#run-a-command-line-tool). This way the custom command is more portable. My example relies on 3.17 though.

```
# SUPER IMPORTANT: Always specify absolute paths!
set(foobar "${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}../projectv/js/all-min.js")

add_custom_command(
    OUTPUT 
       # This is the file your custom command will create
       ${foobar}

    DEPENDS
       # These are all the files you need to run your custom command
       ${JS_FILES}

    COMMAND
       COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E rm ${foobar}
       COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E cat ${JS_FILES} | jsmin >> ${foobar}
)

add_custom_target(MINI-JS ALL DEPENDS ${foobar})
```

Comment: Thanks!  It looks like using ../projectv instead of ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR} was the missing bit.  Yes, jsmin is an executable.  I also needed to change the JS_FILES to use ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}.

Comment: Fantastic! Glad to hear this fixed your problem.

Comment: To be clear the problem was that you were using relative paths. And using absolute paths fixed the problem?

Comment: Absolute paths fixed the issue where the add_custom_command() didn't notice when the files it DEPENDS on were updated.  Tsyvarev's answer/comment did not work without that.

Comment: As a minor comment I'd mention your comment relies on unix pipes.So your custom command isn't gonna work on windows. Consider writing your custom command to not rely on pipes. So it's more cross platform.